# WPF DataGrid with multiple hyperlinks in a cell

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, hyperlink, datagrid

I have a WPF DataGrid like this

```
name | articles
-----+-----------------------
N1   | A1.pdf
N2   | A2.pdf, A5.pdf, A6.pdf
N3   |
```

Now I want every article be clickable like a hyperlink. If one is being clicked I will add a path to the name being displayed and open the file like

```
c:\articles\A5.pdf
```

I have

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
         <DataGridHyperlinkColumn Header="Articles" Binding="{Binding Path=Articles}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

but `DataGridHyperlinkColumn` makes the complete content of the cell as one link clickable. I want to differ between them if multiple articles are in a cell.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `Articles` is, or can be, some sort of list of links you can use `DataGridTemplateColumn` where you put `ItemsControl` with `ItemsSource` bound to `Articles` and each item is separate `HyperLink`

```
<DataGrid ...>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <!-- other columns -->
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Articles">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Articles}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock>
                                    <Hyperlink NavigateUri="{Binding NavigateUri}">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayText}"/>
                                    </Hyperlink>
                                </TextBlock>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: The problem is that the Binding does not work. `<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Articles}">` does not know `Articles`. It works in the  `DataGrid` itself but not in the template

Comment: What is the type of `Articles`? Is it some kind of list? Did you try setting `TextBlock` text to some fixed text instead of binding? Maybe `ItemsSource` binding works fine (as it should) but inner binding does not work and you see list of empty elements. This should work. All bindings in `DataGridTemplateColumn` work in the context of an item

Comment: The DataGrid itself has a Binding to `List<Products>`. And the `Articles` are `List<Article>`. But the VS-Designer does not recognize `Articles` at compile time nor in runtime. I do not set anything especially. It just looks like the Template does not know the Binding of the DataGrid.

Comment: Is `Articles` public property? Since you use `List<T>` (not `ObservableCollection`) when do you initialize it? When do you add items? Is it all in constructor of `Products`? This is something that worked for me many times. I've tested it before adding an answer on a fixed sub list created in constructor of an item but principal stays the same

Comment: I will look further into it. But since it works (without the hyperlinks) when I use it as `<DataGridHyperlinkColumn Header="Articles" Binding="{Binding Path=Articles, Converter={StaticResource ArticleConverter}}" />` it must be something I am missing. But I'll see.

Comment: @juergend if you want to look at my working example then it's [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lhxiqscsmiuf30x/HyperlinkTest.zip?dl=0)